# Open Microsoft word document in C# windows application

Tags: c#, windows, ms-word

I want to open Microsoft word document in C# windows application, but don't want to show Microsoft word formatting and saving controls. I want to implement following steps,
User can open document
modify document in windows application only
user can change formatting only by using formatting toolbar provided by windows application.
User can save document.

Comment: What kind of documents do you want your application could edit? I mean which document format? `*.doc`, `*.rtf`, `*.txt`, `*.docx` ?

Comment: Nice description of what you want to do. And what is the problem?

Comment: Required document format is *.docx, I want word document to be opened on windows form and able to format and save